# Celery task hanging on Django app with Rabbitmq

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm following the [First Steps With Django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) for my app running on a docker container. I have rabbitmq setup on a separate docker container. Opening a python shell to run the task add just results in hanging/freezing without any reports/errors from celery interface. Below are the details.

```
Django version - 3.0.5
Celery - 5.0.2
amqp - 5.0.2
kombu - 5.0.2
Rabbitmq - 3.8.9
```

myapp/myapp/settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'pyamqp://guest:guest@myhost.com//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:111111@myhost.com/celery'
```

myapp/myapp/celery.py

```
import os

from celery import Celery
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

app = Celery('myapp')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
logger.error('in celery')
# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

myapp/myapp/init.py

```
from .celery import app as celery_app
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.error('in init')

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

myapp/otherapp/tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    logger.error('add')
    return x + y
```

Once I run celery -A demolists worker --loglevel=INFO in terminal, I get the following.

```
in celery
in init
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:797: RuntimeWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
absolutely not recommended!

Please specify a different user using the --uid option.

User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0

  warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(ROOT_DISCOURAGED.format(
 
 -------------- celery@3c389cd683b2 v5.0.2 (singularity)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-4.14.186-110.268.amzn1.x86_64-x86_64-with 2020-11-29 22:12:54
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         myapp:0x7f5a52f51c70
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@myhost.com:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:**@myhost.com/celery
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . myapp.celery.debug_task
  . otherapp.tasks.add

[2020-11-29 22:12:55,304: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@myhost.com:5672//
[2020-11-29 22:12:55,337: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-11-29 22:12:56,388: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2020-11-29 22:12:56,412: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:203: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
            leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('''Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory

[2020-11-29 22:12:56,412: INFO/MainProcess] celery@3c389cd683b2 ready.
```

In a separate terminal tab, I go into the python shell and do the following.

```
>>> from otherapp.tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay(4, 5)
```

It hangs here without any change. Control-C produces this error however.

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 32, in __call__
    return self.__value__
AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 143, in _connect
    entries = socket.getaddrinfo(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 325, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 866, in _connection_factory
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 801, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 128, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 322, in connect
    self.transport.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 84, in connect
    self._connect(self.host, self.port, self.connect_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 152, in _connect
    raise (e
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 168, in _connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 421, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 561, in apply_async
    return app.send_task(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 718, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 523, in send_task_message
    ret = producer.publish(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 175, in publish
    return _publish(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 525, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 184, in _publish
    channel = self.channel
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 206, in _get_channel
    channel = self._channel = channel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 34, in __call__
    value = self.__value__ = self.__contract__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 221, in <lambda>
    channel = ChannelPromise(lambda: connection.default_channel)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 884, in default_channel
    self._ensure_connection(**conn_opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 435, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 339, in retry_over_time
    sleep(1.0)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I would appreciate any assistance, very confused by what is happening as on one hand, the celery interface suggests it is connected to rabbitmq, but the error messages in shell suggests there are some issues with that. Thank you in advanced

Comment: Did you started Celery beat service ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus sorry I don't understand? Are you saying I'm suppose to? I don't know what it is and haven't used it yet.